# Simple Injector: Injecting a property in a base class

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

For several weeks I've been using the [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org) dependency injection container, with great success. I love the easy by which I can configure it. But now I have a design that I don't know how to configure. I have a base class where many types from derive, and I want to inject a dependency into a property of the base class, but without having to configure that for every derived class. I tried to do this with attributes, but Simple Injector does not support attributes. Here is a trimmed down version of my design.

```
public interface Handler<TMessage> where TMessage : Message
{
    void Handle(TMessage message);
}

public abstract class BaseHandler
{
    // This property I want to inject
    public HandlerContext Context { get; set; }
}

// Derived type
public class NotifyCustomerHandler : BaseHandler,
    Handler<NotifyCustomerMessage>
{
    public NotifyCustomerHandler(SomeDependency dependency)
    {
    }

    public void Handle(NotifyCustomerMessage message)
    {
    }
}
```

My configuration now looks like this:

```
container.Register<HandlerContext, AspHandlerContext>();
container.Register<Handler<NotifyCustomerMessage>, NotifyCustomerHandler>();
// many other Handler<T> lines here
```

How can I inject the property in the BaseHandler?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Simple Injector [documentation on property injection](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#property-injection) gives a very clear explanation about this. The basic options are:

- Register an initialization delegate using `RegisterInitializer`.
- Override Simple Injector's `PropertySelectionBehavior`.

As the documentation explains, the use of `RegisterInitializer` is not advised for property injection on dependencies; only on configuration values.

This leaves you with overriding Simple Injector's `PropertySelectionBehavior`, but having a base class by itself smells like a SOLID violation. Please take a look at [the following article](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91). It describes why having a base class might be a bad idea and the article presents a solution for this.