# Simple Injector property injection on action filter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, simple-injector

The action filter I want to inject into starts like this

```
public class UserAuthorisation : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public IWcfClientProxy<IAppFrameworkServiceChannel>
        FrameworkServiceProxy { get; set; }
```

I have setup my container like this:

```
container.Register<IWcfClientProxy<IAppFrameworkServiceChannel>>(
    ()=> new WcfClientProxy<IAppFrameworkServiceChannel>());

container.RegisterInitializer<UserAuthorisation>(handler =>
{
    handler.FrameworkServiceProxy = container
       .GetInstance<IWcfClientProxy<IAppFrameworkServiceChannel>>();
});
```

When I run this the `FrameworkServiceProxy` property is null.

I have read this post: [Simple Injector: Injecting a property in a base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227074/simple-injector-injecting-a-property-in-a-base-class) and followed the answer. I have also read example in this page [Simple Injector Documentation](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20the%20Simple%20Injector&referringTitle=Documentation).

I am not injecting into a base class and maybe that is the issue?

#### ## UPDATE ##

I am adding more information as I think it should be working from what has been said in Stevens answer.

I am using the NuGet package for MVC 3. This adds the following to the application:

```
public static class SimpleInjectorInitializer
{
    /// <summary>Initialize the container and register it as MVC3 Dependency Resolver.</summary>
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        InitializeContainer(container);
        container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        container.RegisterMvcAttributeFilterProvider();
        container.Verify();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
    }

    private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<IWcfClientProxy<IAppFrameworkServiceChannel>>(() => new WcfClientProxy<IAppFrameworkServiceChannel>());
        container.RegisterInitializer<UserAuthorisation>(handler =>
            {
                handler.FrameworkServiceProxy = container.GetInstance<IWcfClientProxy<IAppFrameworkServiceChannel>>();
            });
    }
```

This includes the `container.RegisterMvcAttributeFilterProvider();` that as I now understand it should register a filter provider and should mean that filters are created through the container (this understanding might be wrong) and then properties are automatically wired-up.

My filter is registered in the Global.asax.cs like so:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new UserAuthorisation());
}
```

It seems to me that the filter is not being created by the container so I think I need to do something else to get that to happen ?

Comment: How do you register your `UserAuthorisation`? Do you add it to GlobalFilters or Simple Injector has a filterprovider?

Comment: I have added it via global filters, is that where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Yes it is the problem. If the `UserAuthorisation` is not resolved through Simple Injector then Simple Injector won't know about your Filter so cannot do the property injection...

Comment: OK cool, do you want to put that into an answer maybe showing an example of the simple injector filter provider and I will accept it (well if it does work for me :) ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are registering an initializer on your `UserAuthorisation` attribute. Initializers however, are only used by the container when a type is created by the container itself. Since attributes are created by the CLR, the initializer won't go off.

The SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Mvc.dll ([this NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.MVC3)) contains a `RegisterMvcAttributeFilterProvider` extension method. This will register an `AttributeFilterProvider` that will do implicit property injection (and call into the `container.InjectProperties` method). After calling `container.RegisterMvcAttributeFilterProvider()`, you will see that this property is injected automatically.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15755/discussion-between-steven-and-david-mclean)

Comment: This has been deprecated: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/2.8/registermvcattributefilterprovider-is-deprecated.html

Answer (score 5):

I have selected Stevens answer as the answer as it got me to a solution and I am now using the  command handler that he mentioned in the comments.

I have put a simple work around in to get my global filters injected.

In the App_Start\SimpleInjectorInitializer.cs I have added `RegisterGlobalFilters` like this:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters, Container container)
{
    //Add simple injector resolved types.
    filters.Add(container.GetInstance<UserAuthorisation>());
}
```

And in the `Initialize` method I have added this `RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters, container);`

The complete method looks like this:

```
/// <summary>Initialize the container and register it as MVC3 Dependency Resolver.</summary>
public static void Initialize()
{
    var container = new Container();
    InitializeContainer(container);
    container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    container.RegisterMvcAttributeFilterProvider();
    container.Verify();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters, container);
}
```

As I said very simple. Just get my instances from simple injector and then add them to the global list, I am sure there are better ways to do this.

This way does mean you do not need to change the global.asax.cs which is possibly a good thing.

Comment: I simplified your answer a bit. This should do exactly the same, but with less code. Feel free to rollback my edit, if this doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated it again so everything is within the SimpleInjectorInitializer class, so now no changes to the global.asax.cs.

Comment: Note: `RegisterMvcAttributeFilterProvider`  is now obsolete and replaced by `RegisterMvcIntegratedFilterProvider`: http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/registermvcattributefilterprovider-is-deprecated.html