# Simple Injector MVC5 property injection on ActionFilterAttribute not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am working on my MVC5 project using Simple Injector and I hit an issue with DI of properties of my custom class inherited from `ActionFilterAttribute`.

Reading through documentation I've found that there is no way how to use constructor injection for filters and the workaround for this is a property injection which is however by default permitted.

Reading through more documentation I've edited my code to enable property injection, but still whenever I run the project I've got `NullReferrenceException` as the property seems not to be injected at all.

Here is my code:

In App_Start folder I have my `SimpleInjectorConfig.cs` file:

```
public class SimpleInjectorConfig
{
    public static void Config()
    {
        // Create the container as usual.
        var container = new Container();

        container.Options.PropertySelectionBehavior = new ImportPropertySelectionBehavior();


        // Register your types, for instance:
        container.Register<IUserService, UserService>();

        // This is an extension method from the integration package.
        container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // This is an extension method from the integration package as well.
        container.RegisterMvcIntegratedFilterProvider();

        container.Verify();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}

class ImportPropertySelectionBehavior : IPropertySelectionBehavior
{
    public bool SelectProperty(Type type, PropertyInfo prop)
    {
        return prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ImportAttribute)).Any();
    }
}
```

The `Config()` method is called from `Global.asax - Application_Start()` method.

My custom filter class looks like this:

```
public class DatabaseCheckAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   [Import]
   public IUserService UserService { get; set; }

   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //code omitted for better readability
    }
}
```

I don't know if I've missed something from the Simple Injector documentation, but my `IUserService` property of that `DatabaseCheckAttribute` class is still null no matter what.

UPDATE

This is in my opinion not duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086797/simple-injector-property-injection-on-action-filter), since basically the solution suggested there is the implicit property injection, which does not work in my case. In other words I know I need to use implicit/explicit property solution, but I got stuck in implementing it since following 'howtos' didn't help me.

Thanks,
Emil

Comment: I just copy-pasted your code into an empty MVC project, but the `UserService` of the `DatabaseCheckAttribute` is getting injected.

Comment: I would like to suggest not doing any dependency injection into your attributes at all, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915192/unity-property-injection-on-authorizeattribute/29916075#29916075).

Comment: @Steven : Weird. I am using VS2015, the project is targeting 4.5.2 .NET framework. And I am still getting null. Thanks for that article why not to use DI in attributes, I have actually read that prior to post this question, but still wanted to go by the way of explicit property injection.

Comment: I just tried in VS2015 with 4.5.2, but it still works. Are you sure the `ImportPropertySelectionBehavior` and `DatabaseCheckAttribute` reference the same attribute?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915192/unity-property-injection-on-authorizeattribute/29916075#29916075

Comment: Another option - don't put behavior in attributes and then you won't need to inject them. See [passive attributes](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/).