# Resolving issue: ActionFilterAttribute in Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have found this blogpost: http://blog.bitdiff.com/2012/05/sharing-common-view-model-data-in.html?showComment=1499113088147#c5286707438454380796 about sharing strongly-typed common view model data in asp.net mvc, and it look to me like it would solve of the problems I have with keeping track of some user related data across views.

I’m a complete novice when it comes to DI and Unity as I have never used it before, but I have an understanding of the benefits of using it. The post is from May 2012 but should as far as I can see still be valid, perhaps with some small changes.

I’m using C#, MVC 5, EF, Code First, Migrations, Unity V4.01 and Unity.MVC V4.01 with VS2015 Community Edition.

I have followed the blogpost from start to near finish (lacking the test) and all compiles. I have one problem though, this line causes problems:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(container.Resolve<LayoutModelAttribute>(), 1);
```

As far as I can tell the right place to call place the line is in the FilterConfig.cs file in the App_start folder where I’ve done this:

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
        filters.Add(container.Resolve<LayoutModelAttribute>());
    }
```

The container.Resolve gets a squiggly line beneath it and the project won’t compile. The error description is this:

> “The non-generic method 'IUnityContainer.Resolve(Type, string, params
>   ResolverOverride[])' cannot be used with type arguments”

I’ve tried some other places also, but the result is the same, I now lean towards the notion that Unity itself has changed since 2012, and now must be resolved in a different way.

I’m pretty sure I’m doing something wrong and that it properly is because the blogpost is from 2012 and Unity now works in a different way. Due to my lack of experience with Unity, I’m unable to figure out how to change the line of code that won’t compile or to what extend and how to refactor the blogpost if necessary.

I’m hoping someone out there can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried adding a using for Microsoft.Practices.Unity?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using container without it having a capability of injecting. Have a look at the following answer
[Simple Injector property injection on action filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086797/simple-injector-property-injection-on-action-filter)